# How can I modify a Moose attribute handle?

Tags: perl, moose

Following [phaylon's answer to "How can I flexibly add data to Moose objects?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996067/how-can-i-flexibly-add-data-to-moose-objects/3998376#3998376), suppose I have the following Moose attribute:

```
has custom_fields => (
    traits     => [qw( Hash )],
    isa        => 'HashRef',
    builder    => '_build_custom_fields',
    handles    => {
        custom_field         => 'accessor',
        has_custom_field     => 'exists',
        custom_fields        => 'keys',
        has_custom_fields    => 'count',
        delete_custom_field  => 'delete',
    },
);

sub _build_custom_fields { {} }
```

Now, suppose I'd like to croak if trying to read (but not write) to a non-existing custom field. I was suggested by [phaylon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144633/phaylon) to wrap `custom_field` with an around modifier. I have experimented with `around` modifiers following the various examples in Moose docs, but couldn't figure how to modify a handle (rather than just an object method).

Alternatively, is there another way to implement this croak-if-try-to-read-nonexisting-key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're still just methods generated by Moose.  You can just do:

```
around 'custom_field' => sub {
    my $orig  = shift;
    my $self  = shift;
    my $field = shift;

    confess "No $field" unless @_ or $self->has_custom_field($field);

    $self->$orig($field, @_);
};
```

(`croak` is not very useful in method modifiers at the moment.  It will just point you at internal Moose code.)

In fact, you don't need to use `around` for this.  Using `before` is simpler:

```
before 'custom_field' => sub {
    my $self  = shift;
    my $field = shift;

    confess "No $field" unless @_ or $self->has_custom_field($field);
};
```

Comment: @David B, `handles` is creating standard object methods.  An object can't have two methods with the same name.  How would it know which one you were calling?  (Perl 5 doesn't have multimethods.)

Comment: +1 Thank you cjm. I was trying to edit my comment to which you replied, but deleted it accidentally. Just for the record, I was asking something like 'what happens if two attributes have a handle with the same name'. Apparently that's impossible. Thanks again!

Comment: @David just to clarify, the `handles` option is meant to be read as the verb 'handles', not the noun 'handles'. As in "this attribute *handles* these methods", not "this attribute has these handles". It's a delegation tool.