# When and why would you use a class with no data members?

Tags: perl, class, methods, module

I have noticed some Perl modules use a class based structure, but don't manage any data. The class is simply used to access the methods within and nothing more.

Consider the following example:

**Class.pm**

```
package Class;

use Moose;

sub do_something {
    print "Hi!\n";
}

1;
```

**test.pl**

```
use Class;

# Instantiate an object from the class
my $obj = Class->new();

$obj->do_something();
```

In this example you can see that you would first instantiate an instance of the class, then call the method from the created object.

---

The same end result can be achieved like so:

**Module.pm**

```
package Module;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub do_something {
    print "Hi!\n";
}

1;
```

**test.pl**

```
use Module;

Module::do_something();
```

I am wondering why people write modules using the first approach, and if there is some benefit that it provides. To me it seems like it adds an extra step, because in order to use the methods, you first need to instantiate an object of the class.

I don't understand why people would program like this unless it has some benefit that I am not seeing.

Comment: I can think of several reasons, but if you give an example of one of these Perl modules it will be more useful; to explain in context.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was the `CGI` module, but upon closer investigation it looks like it does store data in some circumstances.

Comment: One benefit is inheritance. You can use a subclass of `Module` only if it is object-oriented.

Comment: @mob, actually that may be technically untrue. I was digging through my Perl library directory and it looks like the `DB` module effectively uses inheritance without technically being object oriented. It is very strange though.

Comment: You can add attributes at runtime (unless the class is mutable).  See for instance [posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996067/how-can-i-flexibly-add-data-to-moose-objects). Quite possible to think of use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One benefit is inheritance. You can subclass behavior of an existing class if it supports the `->` style subroutine calls (which is a weaker statement than saying the class is *object-oriented*, as I said in a comment above).

```
package Class;
sub new { bless \__PACKAGE__,__PACKAGE__ }
sub do_something { "foo" }
sub do_something_else { 42 }
1;


package Subclass;
@Sublcass::ISA = qw(Class);
sub new { bless \__PACKAGE__,__PACKAGE__ }
sub do_something_else { 19 }


package main;
use feature 'say';
$o1 = Class->new;
$o2 = Subclass->new;

say $o1->do_something;          # foo
say $o2->do_something;          # foo
say $o1->do_something_else;     # 42
say $o2->do_something_else;     # 19
```

---

A prominent use of this technique is the `UNIVERSAL` class, that all blessed references implicitly subclass. The methods defined in the `UNIVERSAL` namespace generally take a package name as the first argument (or resolve a reference in the first argument to its package name), are return some package information. The `DB` class also does something like this (though the `DB` package also maintains plenty of state).